# Opening a file of which filename matches with a ID in a TSV file (converted from CSV file)

Tags: python, loops, csv, xpath, markdown

I have a TSV file that is converted from a CSV file and a folder that contains markdown files.  What I want to do is to loop over files in a directory, open a file which file name (e.g., "File_ID_1") matches with a value in a column  (column "ID"), extract other relevant contents ("Animal" and "Fruit") from there, and add these in the corresponding columns in the TSV file respectively.

```
example.tsv


ID   Data   Animal   Fruit
1   August
2   July
3   May
...
```

```
File names in a directory 'Desktop/Files':
File_ID_1
File_ID_2
File_ID_3
...
```

```
And markdown file looks like this: 
File_ID_1

**Animal**: Cat

**Fruit**: Peach

...
```

```
This is what I've gotten so far.
## Extracting relevant contents from a matched md file
import csv
import os
import re

df = 'example.tsv'
directory = 'Desktop/Files'

id_to_row = {}
with open(df, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as tsv_file:
    tsv_reader = csv.DictReader(tsv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(tsv_reader):
        id_to_row[int(row['ID'])] = row_idx

# Process markdown files
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.md'):
        id_match = re.match(r'File_ID_(\d+)\.md', filename)
        if id_match:
            file_id = int(id_match.group(1))
            markdown_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            
            with open(markdown_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as md_file:
                content = md_file.read()
```

My colleague suggested me to use Xpath expression to extract the relevant contents from the file, but I'm still a beginner and I'm not sure how to put all these codes together....
I hope my wording is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *regex* to extract the infos then [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the (`.tsv`) with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas

d = {}
for fp in Path("Desktop/Files").glob("*.md"):
    with open(fp, "r") as f:
        pat = r"\*\*(.*)\*\*: (.*)"
        d[int(fp.stem.split("_")[-1])] = {
            m.group(1): m.group(2)
            for m in re.finditer(pat, f.read()) if m
        }
    
df = pd.read_table("example.tsv", index_col=0)
df.update(pd.DataFrame(d).T) # to fill in the existing df
df.to_csv("example.tsv", sep="\t") # to overwrite the file
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/FNBP9T/1)]

Output of the new `example.tsv` (*in a tabular format*) :

| ID | Data | Animal | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | August | Cat | Peach |
| 2 | July |  |  |
| 3 | May |  |  |

Comment: @Timesless Thank you so much ! Yours seems much shorter and neater.  My actual dataset has larger data and is much more complicated, so I guess I have to modify a bit. Just out of curiosity, but do you have compatible codes for Javascript for the same function?

Comment: You're welcome and yes, I suggest you to give a meaningful example that exactly matches the format of your actual dataset and no, unfortuantely, I don't use Javascript. That being said, you can test my code before that and see if it generalizes.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot nevertheless !!